# How do systems typically map an 997 or 999 acknowledgement back to the originating ISA?

Tags: edi, x12

The implementation guides (and most web resources I can find) describe the GS06 and ST02 Control Numbers as being unique only within the Interchange they are contained in. So when we build our GS and ST segments we just start the control numbers at 1 and increment as we add more Functional Groups and/or Transaction Sets. The ISA13 control numbers we generate *are* always unique.

The dilemma is when we receive a 999 acknowledgment; it does not include any reference to the ISA control number that it's responding to. So we have no way to find the correct originating Functional Group in our records.

This seems like a problem that anyone receiving functional acknowledgements would face, but clearly lots of systems and companies handle it, so what is the typical practice to reconcile 997s or 999s? I think we must be missing something in our reading of the guides.

Comment: What happens if you put a "1" in the ISA14?  Your partner might respond back with a TA1, or acknowledgement at the Interchange level.  Typically, in X12, the FA process is done at the group level.  Putting the 1 there means you are requesting it, but it doesn't mean your partner can support it.  If you have EDI Notepad, download it, change the ISA and then use the tool to create the FA and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

GS06 and ST02 only have to be unique within the interchange, but if you use an ID that's truly unique for each one (not just within the message), then you can skip right to the proper transaction set or functional group, not just the right message.

I typically have GS start at 1 and increment the same way that you do, but the ST02 I keep unique (to the extent allowed by the 9 character limit).

Answer (score 1):

GS06 is supposed to be globally unique, not only within the interchange. This is from X12-6

> In order to provide sufficient discrimination for the acknowledgment
>   process to operate reliably and to ensure that audit trails are
>   unambiguous, the combination of Functional ID Code (GS01), Application
>   Sender's ID (GS02), Application Receiver's ID (GS03), and Functional
>   Group Control Numbers (GS06, GE02) shall by themselves be unique
>   within a reasonably extended time frame whose boundaries shall be
>   defined by trading partner agreement. Because at some point it may be
>   necessary to reuse a sequence of control numbers, the Functional Group
>   Date and Time may serve as an additional discriminant only to
>   differentiate functional group identity over the longest possible time
>   frame.